# Avoiding virtual tables in polymorphic classes

Tags: c++, visual-studio, polymorphism

According to [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k13k85ky.aspx), Microsoft's extended attribute `__declspec(novtable)` "stops the compiler from generating code to initialize the vfptr in the constructor(s) and destructor of the class … Using this form of __declspec can result in a significant reduction in code size."

I compiled the following code with Visual Studio 2013 update 4, release configuration, x64 and I obtained the assembler code shown after.

```
struct __declspec(novtable) textEmpty
{
    virtual void fs() = 0;
};

struct textEmpty2
{
    virtual void fs() = 0;
};

struct Y : textEmpty
{
    void fs() override;
};

void Y::fs()
{
    wcout << sizeof( * this ) << endl;
}

struct Y2 : textEmpty2
{
    void fs() override;
};

void Y2::fs()
{
    wcout << sizeof( * this ) << endl;
}

int main()
{
    Y * d_ = new Y;
    Y2 * d_2 = new Y2;
    d_->fs();
    d_2->fs();
    return 0;
}
```

```
    Y * d_ = new Y;
mov         ecx,8
call        operator new (07FF7AEED1090h)
test        rax,rax
je          main+26h (07FF7AEEA2A66h)
lea         rdx,[Y::`vftable' (07FF7AEF189B0h)]
mov         qword ptr [rax],rdx
    Y2 * d_2 = new Y2;
mov         ecx,8
call        operator new (07FF7AEED1090h)
lea         rcx,[Y2::`vftable' (07FF7AEF189C0h)]
test        rax,rax
cmove       rcx,qword ptr [rax]
mov         qword ptr [rax],rcx
```

**Question 1**. I count the same number of instructions in both constructors. In light of Microsoft's claims about  `__declspec(novtable)` reducing code size, am I missing something?

**Question 2**. In the assembler code the `Y2 * d_2 = new Y2;`, the third line modifies RCX and so does the fifth line. RCX is not used in the fourth line. Is there a side effect I am missing?

---

**UPDATE** The compilation flags are below and yes, /O2 has been set. Also, I tried disabling language extensions and enabling it. The result is the same.

> /GS /GL /W3 /Gy /Zc:wchar_t /Zi /Gm- /O2 /sdl /Fd"x64\Release\vc120.pdb" /fp:precise /D "WIN32" /D "NDEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_LIB" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /Gd /Oi /MT /Fa"x64\Release\" /EHsc /nologo /Za /Fo"x64\Release\"

Comment: Intresting... I`m with you on this. Nice research.

Comment: Please specify all the compiler flags you used, and if you didn't try it already it might be worth a quick look at optimised (/02) assembly output.  Which line in your code is the target of the conditional `je`?  Did you check if that branch is being taken?

Comment: The three last instructions don't make sense to me. Apparently they (1) test the relationship between rax and rax itself, (2) if it's equal to itself, copy *rax to rcx, and (3) copy rcx to *rax. Am I completely misreading it?

Comment: @TonyD: Thanks! I thought of `test` as a pseudo-`sub`, and so it's really a pseudo-`and`. Oh okay, so the last instruction copies a value that may or may not have been modified.

Comment: 'fraid so - [test ](en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TEST_%28x86_instruction%29) used this way checks for 0. I think it's effectively checking for nullptr back from `operator new`, (reposting below Alf's response - sorry - as I was removing my last sentence that I'd had second thoughts about).

Comment: @TonyD: I updated the question to include the flags. The `je` jumps to the next statement (`Y2 * d_2 = new Y2;`).

Comment: This is quite a primitive case where the compiler can optimize away all the intermediate vtable loads regardless of `__declspec(novtable)`. To see the difference you need to declare (but not define!) a function, say `void ef(textEmpty*)` and define the constructor `textEmpty::textEmpty() { ef(this); }`; same for `textEmpty2`.

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy: I tried … and I used several combinations of flags, virtual, =0, etc. But I get a linker error LNK2001. How could `ef` be called if it was not defined?

Comment: @Hector, I meant, it mustn't be defined in the same compilation unit. You don't actually need to link your program for the purpose of your study; but if it is easier for you to do so, just create another compilation unit and define the missing functions there. Don't only forget to make sure LTCG is turned off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good questions.  I will give it a shot...

**Question #1:**

__declspec(novtable) does reduce code size, but only for the class that has that attribute, as specified by the documentation:

> In many cases, this removes the only references to the vtable that are
>   associated with **the class** and, thus, the linker will remove it. Using
>   this form of __declspec can result in a significant reduction in code
>   size.

This means that you won't see this effect in the child classes.  I have modified your code to this:

```
struct __declspec(novtable) textEmpty {
    virtual void fs() {};
};
struct textEmpty2 {
    virtual void fs() {};
};
struct Y : textEmpty {
    void fs() override;
};
void Y::fs() {
    wcout << sizeof(*this) << endl;
}
struct Y2 : textEmpty2 {
    void fs() override;
};
void Y2::fs()     {
    wcout << sizeof(*this) << endl;
}
int main() {
    textEmpty* e = new textEmpty;
    textEmpty2* e2 = new textEmpty2;
    Y * d_ = new Y;
    Y2 * d_2 = new Y2;
    d_->fs();
    d_2->fs();
    return 0;
}
```

And the assembly language output is:

```
    textEmpty* e = new textEmpty;
000000013FFB12BA  mov         ecx,8  
000000013FFB12BF  call        qword ptr [__imp_operator new (013FFB3178h)]  
    textEmpty2* e2 = new textEmpty2;
000000013FFB12C5  mov         ecx,8  
000000013FFB12CA  call        qword ptr [__imp_operator new (013FFB3178h)]  
000000013FFB12D0  test        rax,rax  
000000013FFB12D3  je          main+2Fh (013FFB12DFh)  
000000013FFB12D5  lea         rcx,[textEmpty2::`vftable' (013FFB3348h)]  
000000013FFB12DC  mov         qword ptr [rax],rcx  
    Y * d_ = new Y;
000000013FFB12DF  mov         ecx,8  
000000013FFB12E4  call        qword ptr [__imp_operator new (013FFB3178h)]  
000000013FFB12EA  mov         rdi,rax  
000000013FFB12ED  test        rax,rax  
000000013FFB12F0  je          main+4Eh (013FFB12FEh)  
000000013FFB12F2  lea         rax,[Y::`vftable' (013FFB32F0h)]  
000000013FFB12F9  mov         qword ptr [rdi],rax  
000000013FFB12FC  jmp         main+50h (013FFB1300h)  
000000013FFB12FE  xor         edi,edi  
    Y2 * d_2 = new Y2;
000000013FFB1300  mov         ecx,8  
000000013FFB1305  call        qword ptr [__imp_operator new (013FFB3178h)]  
000000013FFB130B  mov         rbx,rax  
000000013FFB130E  test        rax,rax  
000000013FFB1311  je          main+6Fh (013FFB131Fh)  
000000013FFB1313  lea         rax,[Y2::`vftable' (013FFB3300h)]  
000000013FFB131A  mov         qword ptr [rbx],rax  
000000013FFB131D  jmp         main+71h (013FFB1321h)  
000000013FFB131F  xor         ebx,ebx
```

Does it make sense now?  When calling new on a class with novtable, which is textEmpty, the compiler does not generate the vftable pointer initialization code.  On the other hand, new statements for the other three classes, which do not have the novtable attribute, generate the vftable pointer initialization code.

**Question #2:**

For some reason, my compiler outputs something different.  Here are my flags:

> /GS /GL /W3 /Gy /Zc:wchar_t /Zi /Gm- /O2 /Fd"x64\Release\vc120.pdb"
>   /fp:precise /D "WIN32" /D "NDEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_LIB" /D
>   "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /Gd /Oi
>   /MD /Fa"x64\Release\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"x64\Release\"
>   /Fp"x64\Release\sotestaaa.pch"

My output does not have the test and cmove lines like your output does:

```
test        rax,rax
cmove       rcx,qword ptr [rax]
```

but those lines basically translate to

```
 if (rax == 0) mov rcx, [rax]
```

which is really stupid if you ask me.  Those lines would cause a null pointer exception if rax == 0 (i.e. new returns 0).  If rax is not 0, then the code doesn't do anything.

Again, my compiler VS 2013 (12.0.21005.1 REL) does not generate that code.

Note also that my output is sensible.  When novtable is there, it simply does a new and nothing else.  When novtable is not there, it does a new.  If the result of new is not null, then it sets the address of the vftable to the right memory location (as returned by new).

Also note that since, in the c++ code, we call fs() on d and d_2 right after new, the compiler is smart enough to save the pointers to d and d_2 into temporary registers for use later on:

saving d:

```
  mov         rdi,rax
```

saving d_2:

```
  mov         rbx,rax
```